# CD Image to USB bootable flash drive

Tags: boot, usb, images, cd

I have [this](https://archive.org/details/4000-4010-4020-rc-2-win-98-disc-1) CD image that I want to burn onto a USB flash drive, but I keep failing because the "readable part" of the image contains nothing to boot from.

I'm thinking that the image itself might have some kind of program that helps to boot the "readable contents" of the image itself.

Is there any way I can boot the image using a USB flash drive?

EDIT: I feel that I did not explain myself correctly. I have the Toshiba Satellite 4010CDS, and I want to reinstall the OEM windows 98 that came with it. I dont have the original CDs, so I'm using the ISO from web archive. The thing is that it is an `el torito` type ISO, meaning that it cannot be simply put into a USB and using rufus or any kind of USB bootable media creator, and just boot the recovery. Thats the main problem. The second problem is that I cannot find any old stock of blank CDs (the ones that i found are quite expensive), so I cannot make the obvious and burn the ISO onto a CD. I'm able to boot from USBs because I have the Plop boot manager installed.

Comment: CD images are not generally suitable for USB flash drives. Only ISOHybrid images are. Windows 98 predates ISOHybrid by over 15 years.

Comment: can you get the CD contents (not the boot part), save and make a bootlable USB with Rufus.

Comment: well, the thing is that i dont have the file thats used for booting. All of the user-accesable files are useless without the MBR of the CD. That means that rufus is useless in this situation

Comment: It may as well work with Ventoy but I never tested and won't test it (i'm not into retrocomputing other that watching a few YT videos when I'm bored).

Comment: No, Rufus *should* be able to create bootable media anyway, as along as the correct options are selected, MBR/BIOS.

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain your end goal here? **If you intend to create a virtual machine then all you need is the ISO file** and if the goal is to reinstall the machine mentioned in the answer - Toshiba Satellite 4000+ - **those CAN'T boot from USB flash drives**.

Comment: What makes ZERO sense to me?  Your USB stick can not be booted by ANY HARDWARE that this ISO was intended for in the first place.  What the heck are you doing?  I myself feel like you are wasting your time and don't realize it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas My thought exactly. And not the first time for the OP who seems to be into some retrocomputing and/or ancient hardware recovery, which is commendable, but unfortunately approaching it from a very anachronistic line of thinking. And whenever the clarification requests in comments get a little bit "challenging" then we get radio silence...

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself correctly. I have the Toshiba Satellite 4010CDS, and i want to reinstall the OEM windows 98 that came with it. I dont have the original CDs, so i'm using the iso from web archive. The thing is that it is a `el torito` type ISO, meaning that it cannot be simply put into a usb and using rufus make it bootable. Thats the main problem. The second problem is that i cannot find any old stock of blank CDs, so i cannot make the obvious and burn the ISO onto a CD. I'm able to boot from USBs because i have the Plop boot manager installed.

Comment: You'll have to find a CD because, again, it CAN'T boot from USB flash media, period. Even PLoP isn't designed for such old stuff but you may try to simply copy the contents to to USB, who knows? It doesn't have to be bootable if PLoP is booting, it can chainload either way.

Answer (score 0):

Its a "Toshiba Satellite 4000+ System Recovery" from 1998 (W95 or W98 isos).

I'm curious, so I'm downloading to see what it is. It might not be some usual Windows installation CD, but some binary staff as it is said to run ONLY from those specific Toshiba systems. It surely makes some hardware specific tests and perhaps boots only from the specified HW.

When I'll get it, I'll come back with the news.

Meanwhile there is a specific tool to create bootable USB-s from Windows (installation) isos :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/winusbtool/files/latest/download
Try it out. (no more than 4Mo to download)

One other try would be to "chainload" the iso by Grub4Dos. That would be a nice test.
Make your USB bootable by "Grub4Dos" with "Bootice" from here : https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice.html (you cam make it active at the same time by Bootice)
Get Grub4Dos files : https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/
Copy only GRLDR to the root of the USB partition.
Use the provided MENU.LST to make yours, including these lines:

```
title Toshiba Recovery (or whatever)  
find --set-root /4000_4010_4020_RC2_Win98_disc1.iso  
map /4000_4010_4020_RC2_Win98_disc1.iso (hd32)  
map --hook  
chainloader (hd32)  
boot
```

or if it doesn't work, download GrubFileManager iso from here:
https://github.com/a1ive/grub2-filemanager/releases
and do the same.

```
title Grub Filemanager  
find --set-root /grubfm.iso  
map /grubfm.iso (hd32)  
map --hook  
chainloader (hd32)  
boot
```

replace of course "grubfm.iso" with the one of your file...

This will launch the very powerful GFM that will most likely be able to boot your windows type iso.
If you put your iso into a "boot-isos" folder in the root folder, you can also try "supergrub" to boot it. https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/

---

Ok. I saw the file. Its a bootbale iso, actually booting as a floppy. The bootable floppy image is W98V321P.GER at the root of the iso.
But it makes a bios check, so if you are not on the original 25 years old machine it will not get you further.

[image: the message you get (a picture) if the bioscheck fails]

But there is a way:
0. Extract the iso somewhere on your hard drive.

1. Extract the floppy image, inside it, as well in a separate folder.
2. In the floppy image files edit autoexec.bat : delete the section ":TOSHCHK"
3. Always in autoexec.bat, replace all occurence of "Z:" by D (because when booting from (chainloading) this floppy image in Grub4Dos it will try to mont the physical CD drive as Z: but you will have only D: as the USB partition - that you will need to format by the way as FAT16 to be sure it will be able to read from it the system image file.
   3+. Replace Z: in \DUALINST\TOOLS\DUALINST.BAT as well.
4. that supposes as well that in your target system/pc  you have prepared a FAT16 (max 2Go, activated) partition as well, that it will recognize as the internal C: drive.
5. repack the floppy image. Put it back to the extracted iso folder (replacing the original floppy image)
6. copy all files to the USB fat16 partition you prepared with Grub4dos installed (+GRLDR and the menu.lst).
7. add this section to the menu.lst :

   ```
   title Toshiba Recovery floppy  
   find --set-root /W98V321P.GER  
   map --mem /W98V321P.GER (fd0)  
   map --hook  
   rootnoverify (fd0)  
   map --floppies=1  
   chainloader (fd0)+1  
   boot
   ```

Boot your target machine with the USB key (provided its BIOS supports this, if not you can do it directly from the hard drive using the same process as described, just replacing Z: by C: and not D: because there will then be no USB)

But if it wants to overwrite the whole disk, it will be a problem.
Therefore you could better chainload the whole iso from a second hard drive (or a from small 400Mo second fat16 partition on the same disk which will then recognized as D: -> C with Grub would than be overwritten, but could be reinstalled) if USB is not supported by the BIOS (and if it's not about a laptop) - you can use old IDE hard drives. Providing you change the file mentioned above to avoid the BIOS check.

Same applies if it is used in a virtual machine (using a preformatted fat16 partition/disk image).

If you have the right old Toshiba PC, of course, no problem.

I didn't go through all the installation process, but this will give you a chance. It might fail also if the hardware (real or emulated in VM) is not at least compatible to the desired one.

Final note:

Booting it is not the problem, but making it work.
Tried on a VM, but failed. There are multiple checks for a Toshiba system (not only the bios check I found first). With even no CD-rom device loaded it still looks for "TOSCD001" and locks you out. (IO.SYS looks to be a Toshiba fork)
And the proprietary filesystem decompressor itself 'F3DCHK.EXE' checks again for some computed value (from SETENV.BAT) we cannot know where it is gathered.

I don't see any means to get something from it that worth the effort/result.

Comment: Although (mostly) correct it doesn't consider the specific and, at the time of this writing, still *undisclosed* end goal as asked in this comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1766700/cd-image-to-usb-bootable#comment2749559_1766700 . So, if this is for VM it's a X-Y problem; if it's to use in any real machine then nothing supporting the ancient OS is able to boot from USB flash media regardless of the Grub4DOS presence to chainload. It may be possible to boot from something like PLoP (bootable CD) and then chainload to the USB but even that is highly doubful.

Comment: @martinist I Have the notebook so no problem there. So far i followed all your instructions, but im having a problem at the format section. It hard resets the computer. Its still executing stuff from the floppy. Looking at the AUTOEXCEC.BAT, it seems that its having problems in the `:PART_FORM`. The problem must be one of the two commands executed after the `choice` command. I havent found any data online about what they do. I know it isnt copying any files because i see no disk activity.

Comment: I also made sure that the setup didnt do anything with the CD drive, so i commented with REM all the MSCDEX calls

Comment: Yeah. I did the same, however I still got the mscdex error. So there seem to be an unconditional check on this.  Again, the IO.sys is proprietary. And the vorst is that the fs decompressor has a system check implemented as well. So probably even if you would get through with the mscdex thing, there would still be tha last final step of the decompression that would fail anyway, so no chance to make it work outside a Toshiba system. :-/

Comment: At the end I was able to install windows 98 succesfully. I just had to avoid using the default scripts and do all manually using the transfered sys. But, i did all that work just to discover that windows98 dosent support language packs, and given that i dont speak german, all this work was for nothing. at least i enjoyed the process

Comment: Good try! :-)  But, frankly, you can get easily an english copy of a W98 as iso or WM file. Search for it (use alternative search engines).

Comment: Oups, I've seen your comment from "Feb.4 at 2:57" just now. (too late, you solved it :-)